# Why doesn't my linear-gradient work in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, linear-gradients

I'm testing my application on Firefox 33. I have a simple background property defined with a gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(bottom, #004771 0%, #005185 100%);
```

and it doesn't work. **[CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient)** reports that gradients on Firefox 33 can be used without a prefix. So why doesn't it work? If I add a Mozilla-specific prefix:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #004771 0%, #005185 100%);
```

everything works OK.

Comment: isnt it because the syntax changed? is your gradient syntax correct to the old (and therefore prefixed) syntax? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient see the docs here.

Comment: Caniuse isn't very useful with the exact syntax to be used. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ has all the versions (like the very old one with color-stop that you can forget as it's Chrome 9-, different from another prefixed one for Chrome 10+)

Comment: @FelipeAls, thanks. I do use `colorzilla` occasionaly, but I'm I either use bootstrap's mixins or lately `autoprexer` to do the job for me. However, as I've found out with gradients, it's not bulletproof :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using linear-gradient without the prefix, you need to write it like this ("to bottom" instead of "bottom"):

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004771 0%, #005185 100%);
```

EDIT: Link to documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `to bottom` in order for it to work:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004771 0%, #005185 100%);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ucxd15k/)

Comment: why has someone downvoted? Please leave a comment so I can understand why it is wrong.